# Integrating $\int_{0}^{1} x^a (1-x)^b (1-2x)^c \, \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, beta-function

**Problem**

> How can I integrate $$\int_{0}^{1} x^a (1-x)^b (1-2x)^c \, \mathrm dx $$ where $a,b,c$ are some constants.

**Solution Attempt**

I've tried using Beta Function and integrate it by parts, however, it didn't work.

Comment: what are a,b and c?

Comment: non-negative constants

Comment: Solution by `Hypergeometric2F1` function.CAS says.

Comment: Not sure how useful might be, but you could try to compute the integral first for $c\in\mathbb N$, and then check if there is some *natural* interpolation to use as a guess.

Comment: I believe it would look better if you used **\mathrm dx** to generate $\mathrm dx$, by the way.

Comment: That's exactly a way for *defining* ${}_2 F_1$.

Comment: Is this even integrable?

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer, why wouldn't it be, in general? Of course, for particular values of the parameters, the function might not exist, but it's pretty easy to recognize them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a Beta function in the general case.

As stated in the comments, it's the Hypergeometric function.

The Euler integral for this function has the following form:

$${_2 F_1} (\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z)=\frac{1}{B(\beta,\gamma-\beta)} \int_0^1 t^{\beta-1} (1-t)^{\gamma-\beta-1} (1- zt)^{-\alpha} dt$$

Where Beta function still appears.

Now apply this definition for your case.

Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are interchangeable in this function, so you get two different integral definitions, which of course give the same values.

For the other ways to express the function and for its properties, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function